# ReasonPhrase Not Acceptable HTTPClient C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, httpclient

I am trying to send a json object with a base4 encoded file to a web api service using the code below

```
                MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                q.fileUpload.InputStream.CopyTo(target); //q.fileUpload is an HttpPostedFilebase pdf
                var myfile= Convert.ToBase64String(target.ToArray());
                var requestbody = new {
                    filedata = new
                    {
                        mimetype = "application/pdf",
                        basedata = "base64-data=" + myfile
                    }
                };
                var jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestbody );
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://web.base.url/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", "SOMEAPIKEY");
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "upload");
                request.Content = new StringContent(jsondata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                var responsetask= client.SendAsync(request);
                return Json(responsetask);
```

But i everytime i call this i get a `406` `Not Acceptable` response. Anyone knows what causes it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406

Comment: @mjwills i've read that. then what's next?

Comment: What happened to be the contents of the response body? Is there perhaps a documentation for the API that details the supported Accept-* header values?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek In which part of the response can i possibly see that? I'm sorry I'm new to web api

Comment: You can access the response body through `Content` property. e.g. `var response = await client.SendAsync(request); var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. I'm not sure off the top of my head, but it's possible that doing this will consume the content so it will not be available further. If evaluating in debugger, you can use `Wait` on the tasks instead of await so that the debugger thread blocks until the result is available (if this is a good idea for a network request is up to you - don't be surprised if your IDE hangs for a while).

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek is this content-length, content-type, expires thing in the headers?

Comment: Ok, so to start with, HTTP requests and responses consist of three parts: request line, headers and body. The request line specifies protocol and version, requested URL etc. (note: this is imprecise, see actual HTTP spec for accurate description). Headers contain additional request metadata. The content is in the body. The type and size of content is defined by `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers. Does the code I wrote above or a variant thereof not work for you? What errors do you get with it?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek how do i do this on a non async method?

Comment: Ideally make the method async. I would assume that this is a controller method so there should be no problem with that - although I am no ASP.NET MVC expert. The alternative is to use the `Wait` on the returned tasks as mentioned before (definitely not recommended as this blocks the thread and may also cause deadlocks but may be sufficient for quick debugging).

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek i am getting this on the body message, " There was an error with your request. Please check your payload and then try again"

Comment: Then check the web API documentation or contact its operator/developer for support.